# cmake: target_link_libraries use static library not shared

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

Is it possible to tell cmake to link against a **static library** instead of **shared**?

At the top of my `CMakeLists.txt` I have the following configured:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
```

Later, I add a binary, and tell it to link against `tcmalloc` in release mode:

```
target_link_libraries(${BIN_NAME} optimized tcmalloc_minimal)
```

The resulting makefile links aginst the shared version of `tcmalloc`:

```
$ make VERBOSE=1 | grep tcmalloc
/usr/bin/c++ ... -Wl,-Bdynamic ltcmalloc_minimal
```

Further proof:

```
$ ldd app 
    ...
    libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 => /usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 (0x00007eff89733000)
    ...
```

Both static and shared versions of tcmalloc exist:

```
$ ls -1 /usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal*
/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.a
/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.a
/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.la
/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so
/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.4
/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.4.2.6
/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.la
/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so
/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4.2.6
```

**Question:**

How can I configure cmake to link against the static version of `tcmalloc`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a helper function which sets `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` at function scope ([so therefore doesn't affect the parent scope](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/function.html)) which searches for the library in question and sets an output variable with the result

```
function(find_static_library LIB_NAME OUT)

    if (WIN32 OR MSVC)
        set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".lib")
    elseif (UNIX)
        set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
    endif()      

    find_library(
        FOUND_${LIB_NAME}_STATIC
        ${LIB_NAME}
        )

    if (FOUND_${LIB_NAME}_STATIC)
        get_filename_component(ABS_FILE ${FOUND_${LIB_NAME}_STATIC} ABSOLUTE)
    else()
        message(SEND_ERROR "Unable to find library ${LIB_NAME}")
    endif()

    set(${OUT} ${ABS_FILE} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction()
```

You can then call this function from somewhere in your `CMakeLists.txt` to populate a variable with the location of the library.

Failure to find it results in a hard failure

```
find_static_library(tcmalloc_minimal TCMALLOC)
```

You can then use this variable in your call to `target_link_libraries` and be sure you're linking against the static version

```
target_link_libraries(${BIN_NAME} optimized ${TCMALLOC})
```

Here you can see the result:

```
$ make VERBOSE=1 | grep tcmalloc
```

> ```
> /usr/bin/c++ ... /usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.a ...
> ```

Comment: you need to add `    unset(FOUND CACHE)` before the find_library call or else the second find_static_library won't work.

Comment: @over_optimistic very late reply, but I updated the answer to undo the need for the `unset`

Comment: This is a minor nit-pick of a great answer, but it's awkward that you chose a different argument order than [cmake's built-in `find_library()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html).  The built-in order is `find_library(VAR name)`, but the function above is `find_static_library(name VAR)`.  If you fix the order, that would help those of us lazy programmers who blindly find-and-replace.

Comment: This does not work on OSX

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to support non-Windows platforms, then [this old email](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-December/041326.html) from the CMake mailing list from one of the Kitware developers gives the simplest method. In essence, use `find_library()` to find the location of the actual library, favouring static libraries over shared ones by listing them first in the names to look for. i.e.

```
find_library(TCMALLOC_LIB NAMES libtcmalloc_minimal.a tcmalloc_minimal)
```

You would then link to the library found in the usual way:

```
target_link_libraries(${BIN_NAME} ${TCMALLOC_LIB})
```

You could get smarter about how you define the static library name if you need to support platforms where a static library is named something other than `lib???.a`. You would use CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX and CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX variables for that.

On Windows, the problem is that you cannot distinguish between a static library and the import library for a DLL, as discussed in [this old issue](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=1643) in the Kitware bug tracker. Both have the file extension `.lib`, so you can't use the extension to work out if a particular file is a static library or not, unlike Unix-based platforms where you can.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES variable in this manner:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a)
```

because in default CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES there is also .so suffix (and it seems not searching in order of insertion). In order to allow portability other suffixes should be added (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194215/default-values-for-cmake-find-library-prefixes-cmake-find-library-suffixes) for default values of CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES on different platforms).

Comment: That didn't work - I did just what you suggested, and it still links against the shared lib. According to the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html) that setting is only for `find_library` not for `target_link_libraries`

Comment: Yes, it requires using find_library. Usually I use find_library to find external libraries and store them in CMake variables; then I add them to target libraries using variables.

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243524/cmake-find-library-matching-behavior. Then you need to add the library var to TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES with ${VAR_LIBRARY_NAME}.If you have problems try to print variable obtained through find_library with message(STATUS ...) to understand if it has found the right library.