How to include OpenMP libraries in CPack package on macOS?
I am getting familiar with CMake and CPack, but I can't figure out how to solve the following issue when creating a macOS package.
I have some C++ code using OpenMP:
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        std::cout << "Hallo Welt... von Thread = " << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

What I would like to do is to create a package containing the main executable as well as the shared OpenMP libraries (which I was able to do), and the that the executable is able to find the libraries within the package (this is the problem).
This is the associated CMakeLists.txt so far:
# Set the minimum required CMake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

# Set the project name
project(OpenMPExample)

# Find OpenMP package
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

# Add the executable target
add_executable(parallel-hallo parallel-hallo.cpp)

# Link the OpenMP library
target_link_libraries(parallel-hallo PRIVATE OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)

# Install main executable and runtime dependencies
install(TARGETS parallel-hallo RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET OpenMP RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET OpenMP DESTINATION lib)

include(CPack)

libomp has been installed via Homebrew.
When creating the package, I obtain the expected file structure, i.e.:
OpenMPExample-0.1.1-Darwin/bin:
parallel-hallo*

OpenMPExample-0.1.1-Darwin/lib:
libomp.dylib*

But the executable looks for the libomp library at its original location, and it fails because the library is not found.
I can solve the issue by modifying the executable manually after it has been generated using install_name_tool or modifying DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, but how can I do it directly with CMake/CPack?
I have tried to play with the RPATH CMake variables but without success so far. Installing the library in the same directory as the executable didn't work either.
Thank you in advance for any advice.
What I get when running the executable on a platform without OpenMP installed:
/Users/user/Downloads/OpenMPExample-0.1.1-Darwin/bin/parallel-hallo ; exit;
dyld[4755]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: <59DF0FF4-9EF7-338A-87BC-6A25C972D9D4> /Users/user/Downloads/OpenMPExample-0.1.1-Darwin 2/bin/parallel-hallo
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

What is expected: the executable excutes without error, i.e. something like
Hallo Welt... von Thread = Hallo Welt... von Thread = 03Hallo Welt... von Thread = 2

Hallo Welt... von Thread = 
1


CPack only considers libraries built within your project for packing. It doesn't consider external dependencies. One choice is to link OpenMP statically into your application. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36754678/8136338 describes how to find a static library. Setting this CMake variable before find_package(OpenMP) will find  the static OpenMP library for linking. You would need to have the static library available as well. I'm not sure whether macos is identified as UNIX, or you would need to add another case. The suffix for static libraries should still be ".a".

Be extremely careful if statically linking in the OpenMP library. If you end up with more than one of them in the process, you will very likely see each of them start their own thread-pool, which will result in over-subscription and poor performance. (This aside from the possibility of correctness issues, which can certainly arise if you think you can avoid GCC and LLVM compatibility problems by having both runtimes in the process (see https://cpufun.substack.com/p/is-mixing-openmp-runtimes-safe )).

This question is similar to: Building OSX App Bundle. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
