Global variable marked as extern is duplicated
I am linking a shared library that declares a global variable like so:
__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) extern HookList<MallocHook::DeleteHook> delete_hooks_;

See src/malloc_hook-inl.h:122 for declaration and src/malloc_hook.cc:240 for definition.
However, it looks like it is duplicated despite being declared as extern. With 2 different stack traces the addresses of delete_hooks_ are different. Compare stacktraces from the LLDB debugger and values for this when stepping into lines 7 and 8 of main.cpp in a single execution. The address ranges were located with /proc/PID/map.
Stacktrace 1:
this == 0x5574f1215968 <- belongs to main binary's (Example) address space

base::internal::HookList<void (*)(const void *)>::Add(void (*)(const void *)) malloc_hook.cc:155
::MallocHook_AddDeleteHook(MallocHook_DeleteHook) malloc_hook.cc:265
MallocHook::AddDeleteHook(void (*)(const void *)) malloc_hook.h:115
::HeapProfilerStart(const char *) heap-profiler.cc:454
main main.cpp:7

Stacktrace 2:
this == 0x7efe998baa28 <- belongs to libtcmalloc.so's address space

base::internal::HookList<void (*)(const void *)>::empty() const malloc_hook-inl.h:88
[Inlined] free_fast_path(void *) tcmalloc.cc:1944
::tc_free(void *) tcmalloc.cc:1953
main main.cpp:8

My questions:

Why is the variable duplicated? Isn't the extern keyword supposed to prevent it from happening?
How can this duplication be avoided?
Am I misusing the library? I believe I have followed the instructions precisely. See https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html

Complete example and other important bits of information:

I am using LLVM toolchain 19.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.
Additional cmake flags are -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang-19 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++-19
I am using gperftools 2.15 from https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools

# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28) # likely compatible with an older version too

project(Example LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(Example main.cpp)

set(gperftools_build_benchmark OFF CACHE BOOL "Build gperftools benchmark" FORCE)
set(PATH_TO_GPERFTOOLS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/gperftools")
add_subdirectory(${PATH_TO_GPERFTOOLS})
target_link_libraries(Example tcmalloc)
target_include_directories(Example PRIVATE ${PATH_TO_GPERFTOOLS}/src)

// main.cpp

#include <cstdlib>
#include "gperftools/heap-profiler.h"

int main() {
    HeapProfilerStart("/tmp/example");  // stacktrace #1
    std::free(nullptr);                 // stacktrace #2
    HeapProfilerStop();
    return 0;
}


where is delete_hooks_ defined? please show a [mre]

@AlanBirtles I've updated the description to include links to both the declaration and definition of delete_hooks_. The minimum reproducible example is provided at the bottom of the description. Is anything missing?

@Botje tcmalloc is bundled with gperftools 2.15. The link to the repository is provided in the description. Here it is for convenience once again - https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools. I had an impression that this is the official one.

Can you show the code of the actual hooks you inserted? The ones that print the this == and the stacktrace?

Actually, google/TCMalloc diverged significantly from the tcmalloc implementation bundled with gperftools. Only the latter has support for the hooks you mention. Supplying more than one memory allocator to a process is definitely a recipe for disaster.

@Botje the stacktrace and the value for this are taken from the debugger (lldb). There is no code that prints it. The main.cpp plus the gperftools repository is everything that is compiled. A default delete hook is set up by the HeapProfilerStart function from gperftools.

@Botje I don't use a different tcmalloc implementation or any other allocator. Only the one provided by gperftools.

visibility("hidden") means it isn't actually globally global.  Which is the important part of being global.

@Eljay could you please elaborate on your answer? Given the extern keyword and hidden visibility I would expect a single instance of the variable to be present in the library and nowhere else outside. How did I get a duplicate of the variable in my main binary?

@VolodymyrLashko You explicitly linked TCMalloc to your application in your CMakeLists.txt.

@Botje could you please elaborate a bit more? Why do you believe that multiple memory allocators are used? The tcmalloc (supplied by gperftools) linked in CMakeLists.txt is the only allocator used in the program.

Nevermind, I missed the add_subdirectory directly above it..

Are those stack traces from the same execution? Also, please post the code of you hooks as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78782910/global-variable-marked-as-extern-is-duplicated#comment138901740_78782910

@Enbyted yes, the 2 stack traces are from the same execution. I've updated the description to clarify this. I didn't fully understand your request on posting the code for hooks. Could you please rephrase it? The code consisting of main.cpp and gperftools repository is all there is. I don't add any additional hooks besides the ones set by HeapProfilerStart.

@VolodymyrLashko I was consused by the this == xx output. That is information you extracted manually via debugger, not via code, correct?   I have a feeling that CMake is doing you a disfavor of linking tcmalloc dynamically. Try building in verbose mode (ex. cmake -B <builddir> --build --verbose or make VERBOSE=1 to inspect. See this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36754160/3449622 I'm not entirely sure how this would lead to double symbol yet.

Also, how are you running your Example application?

@Enbyted tcmalloc is linked as a dynamic library and it is intentional. This method is advised by the developers - https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html
I simply type ./Example in the terminal or run it through a debugger (LLDB). There is nothing special about it.

As you are building those libraries as dynamic - are you sure that the OS is loading the correct copy? Perhaps you have one installed in your system and they are getting confused somehow? Perhaps std::free is going via libstdc++ which is linking a different version of tcmalloc than the oneyour executable is linking with? I know something like this could happen on Windows, not sure about Linux.
