# Cmake find module to distinguish shared or static library

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a cmake c++ project that uses libCrypto++. I have FindCryptoPP.cmake module hosted [here](https://github.com/mateuszzz88/FindCryptoPP.cmake/blob/master/cmake/FindCryptoPP.cmake). Important parts are:

```
find_library(CryptoPP_LIBRARY
  NAMES cryptopp
  DOC "CryptoPP library"
  NO_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH
  PATHS "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"
)
...
add_library(CryptoPP::CryptoPP UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(CryptoPP::CryptoPP PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CryptoPP_LIBRARY}"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CryptoPP_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

And this works fine, finds static library file (*.a). Now I would like to create separate targets CryptoPP::CryptoPP-static and CryptoPP::CryptoPP-shared.
Necessary files are installed (default ubuntu install):

- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptopp.a
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptopp.so

I want to know how to tell find_library to search either static or shared version (preferably in portable way - I need all of Linux, Windows, MacOS) and specify the type created target.

Comment: As far as I know, when search libraries, CMake doesn't distinguish static and shared ones. All it has is the lists of possible library's prefixes and suffixes. And *NAMES* option, of course. You may affect on CMake preferences by **either** changing possible library's prefixes and suffixes (note, they are global, so you need to change them before every `find_library` call) **or** specify in *NAMES* **exact library file** to search: `NAMES libcryptopp.so`. As for portability... you may check target platform and then specify corresponded file. Or you may list *NAMES* for all possible platforms.

Answer (score 8):

Actually CMake's default is to search first for shared libraries and then for static libraries.

The key is the order of values in the [`CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html) global variable, which is e.g. set in [`CMakeGenericSystem.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeGenericSystem.cmake#L25) as part of CMake's compiler/platform detection of the [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) command to:

```perl
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".so" ".a")
```

For a solution take a look at an existing find module like [`FindBoost.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L1553):

```perl
# Support preference of static libs by adjusting CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
if( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS )
  set( _boost_ORIG_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
  if(WIN32)
    list(INSERT CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES 0 .lib .a)
  else()
    set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a)
  endif()
endif()
```

Here the `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` variable is temporarily changed for the [`find_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) calls.

Same should be applicable here. Just be aware the `find_library()` does cache its results if you want to do the same search twice.

#### References

- [Default values for CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194215/default-values-for-cmake-find-library-prefixes-cmake-find-library-suffixes)
- [CMake find_library matching behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243524/cmake-find-library-matching-behavior)
- ['find_library' returns the same value in the loop in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49959572/find-library-returns-the-same-value-in-the-loop-in-cmake)