# CMAKE not finding GUROBI external library

Tags: c++, cmake, gurobi

I am new to CPP, to GUROBI and specially to CMAKE. I am working on a project and I am trying to compile a C++ program, that needs to link to the GUROBI external libraries `libgurobi81.so` and `libgurobi_c++.a` as explained in the GUROBI site [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/quickstart_linux/software_installation_guid.html#section:Installation) and [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/quickstart_linux/cpp_building_and_running_t.html).
The structure of my cmake and my project is something like this:

```
-folder1
--src
---cmake
--gurobi
---lib
----libgurobi81.so
----libgurobi_c++.a
```

My code compiles correctly, but it only fails when linking with the libraries.
I tried to make CMAKE to find the libraries:

```
find_library(C_GUROBI_LIB NAMES libgurobi81.so gurobi81 gurobi81_light                                                  
    PATHS   ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
            /path/to/folder1/gurobi/lib/
        )
find_library(CPP_GUROBI_LIB NAMES gurobi_c++
    PATHS   ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
            /path/to/folder1/folder1/gurobi/lib/
    )
```

and then to print it:

```
message("C_GUROBI_LIB points to " ${C_GUROBI_LIB})
message("CPP_GUROBI_LIB points to " ${CPP_GUROBI_LIB})
```

However, even if the library is in that folder CMAKE do not find it and shows nothing:

```
C_GUROBI_LIB points to 
CPP_GUROBI_LIB points to
```

Comment: Did you try using absolute instead of relative paths?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In  my question I wrote: ../folder1/gurobi/lib/ and it may seem that it was relative. But in fact I meant that there were some other folders. I am using an absolute path in both cases: /var/tmp/folder1/ ...
I even tried to use:
 SET (CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "/var/tmp/folder1/gurobi810/linux64/lib/")
include_directories(/var/tmp/folder1/gurobi810/linux64/lib/)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/var/tmp/folder1/gurobi810/linux64/lib/)
But to no avail...

Comment: Result variable of the `find_library` cannot be an *empty string*: it should be either **absolute path** or `*-NOTFOUND` string. Try to clear build directory and repeat the configuration step (running `cmake`).

Comment: You're right!...turns out it was a typo. However, it finds only the second library: CPP_GUROBI_LIB, that is, the location of libgurobi_c++.a. However, even if the libgurobi81.so is in the same folder, it is not finding it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121295/cmake-find-module-to-distinguish-shared-or-static-library):

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".so" ".a")
```

I had some other issues, for example the library was compiled for 64 bits, and also that CMAKE did not allow to add Shared files. So I got to change some parameters, but even with that, CMAKE did not found the file.